# How can I add one more value to my Map<Integer>, List<String>>?

Tags: java, list, collections, hashmap

I have this solution to add "c" to my map, but is there another way to do what I want in one line?

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
map.put(1, list);

list.add("c");
map.put(1, list);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need that last call to `map.put(1, list)`, as `list` is already the value pointed to by the key 1, so I guess that's a oneliner.

If you meant replacing the entire update of the map with a oneliner, you could use something like `Arrays.asList`:

```
map.put(1, Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using `Map.computeIfAbsent`.  If the key is absent or points to a null the supplied value will be used (in this case an `ArrayList<String>` instance) and return it, otherwise it uses the one already present.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

map.computeIfAbsent(1, v -> new ArrayList<>()).add("a");
map.computeIfAbsent(1, v -> new ArrayList<>()).add("b");
map.computeIfAbsent(2, v -> new ArrayList<>()).add("b");
map.computeIfAbsent(1, v -> new ArrayList<>()).add("c");
map.computeIfAbsent(2, v -> new ArrayList<>()).add("e");
map.computeIfAbsent(3, v -> new ArrayList<>()).addAll(List.of("f","g","h"));
map.computeIfAbsent(3, v -> new ArrayList<>()).add("i");
                       
map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
1=[a, b, c]
2=[b, e]
3=[f, g, h, i]
1=[a, b, c]
2=[e, f, g]
```

You can of course use lambdas or explicit methods to facilitate the process

Comment: Be careful!  In my answer I was providing a general case so you wouldn't have problems.  If you do `map.put(1, Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));` You won't be able to add another value to that list as it is immutable.  If you do  `map.computeIfAbsent(1, v -> new ArrayList<>()).addAll(List.of("a", "b","c"));`  you will since it creates a mutable array list prior to adding the values to it.  And that line is the one liner you asked for.  The others were part of the demo.  And it protects against accidentally adding another list for key `1` later on.

Answer (score 1):

*UPDATED*

You can use Stream.of() to create the initial list. After that if you want to add new values only it's necessary add to the list because the reference of the object is the same.

```
List<String> list = Stream.of("a", "b");
map.put(1, list);
list.add("c");
```

Comment: No, you can't, because `Arrays.asList` create a new unmodifiable list. SO it will throw an error

Comment: It's true thank you, but an other one line option is Stream.of() in stead of Arrays.asList, I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it after declaration you can do this

```
        Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1,List.of("a","b","c"));
```

At declaration you may do

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>(Map.of(1,List.of("a", "b", "c")));
```

In case you don't know how to access a specific element on the list should you need to, you'd do it like

```
map.get(1).get(i)
```

where i, is the index of the list